# Show that is $\int_A f$ exists, then so does $\int_A |f|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $A$ in $E^n$. Show that is $\int_A f$ exists, then so does $\int_A |f|$ and $\left | \int_A f\right | \le \int_A |f|$.

I am trying to finish Rosenlicht's *Introduction to Analysis* and the last chapter is awful. But I do want to finish it because I have come this far. Could someone show me how to do this, so I can at least have some example problems to understand the material. This chapter (Multiple Integrals) really just left more confused than before I started reading the chapter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $A$? This result seems incorrect, $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{sin x}{x}$ would be a counter-example.

Comment: $A \subset E^n$ Also, assume $A$ is closed interval to simplify the problem.

Comment: @Jack I think $A$ is bounded (it should be otherwise this is wrong).

Comment: @Hamed Yes I believe you are correct, even though the problem statement is exactly as stated above.

Comment: By definition, Riemann integrable functions are bounded. To show the first part, note that for every partition $P$ and every cell $c$ in $P$, $\sup\limits_c|f|-\inf\limits_c|f|\leqslant\sup\limits_cf-\inf\limits_cf$ hence $U(|f|,P)-L(|f|,P)\leqslant U(f,P)-L(f,P)$, which shows that $|f|$ is Riemann integrable. For the second part, note that $-|f|\leqslant f\leqslant|f|$.

Comment: @Did this is pretty much the answer I was looking for, if you copy it to the answer section I will give you the credit. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but these are at most succinct hints. Please expand them into a full answer and post it below, after a while you may even accept it.

Comment: I am sorry but I am having trouble actually writing out the proof for the first part. Is there any way you could show me how to do the first part? (especially the part where you say "hence")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that the integral of absolute value of $f$ exists if $f$ is integrable.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542984/show-that-the-integral-of-absolute-value-of-f-exists-if-f-is-integrable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the statement is false: $\int_0^\infty {{\sin x}\over{x}} dx$ is well-defined by the alternating series theorem, but $\int_0^\infty |{{\sin x}\over{x}}| dx$ is not.

The statement is true if $A$ is closed and bounded (hence compact). In that case, any continuous measure $\mu$ on $A$ is finite, and so $\int_A f d\mu \leq \infty$ if and only if $f$ is finite a.e. with respect to $\mu$. If $f$ is a.e. finite, then so is $|f|$, from which the first part of the result follows.

The second part follows from Jensen's inequality. $|\cdot|$ is convex on the real line, and hence

$$ {\biggl |}\int_A f d\mu \biggr | \leq \int_A |f| d\mu $$

Comment: I realize that I gave an over-general answer, I guess. Your problem concerns only continuous functions and Riemann integration, so of worrying about a general continuous measure, you can simply consider Lebesgue measure, which corresponds to Riemann integration. The integral is well-defined only if the function is bounded, and the rest goes through as before.

(Edited to correct a misspelling.)