# Show that the integral of absolute value of $f$ exists if $f$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $A$ in $E^n$. Show that is $∫_Af$ exists, then so does $∫_A|f|$.

I have been given an outline of what I need to do, however, I have been unable to actually formulate it into a rigorous proof. Here is the outline:

By definition, Riemann integrable functions are bounded. Note that for every partition $P$ and every cell $c$ in $P$, $\sup_c|f|−\inf_c|f|⩽\sup_c f−\inf_c f$ hence $U(|f|,P)−L(|f|,P)⩽U(f,P)−L(f,P)$, this should show that $|f|$ is Riemann integrable.

EDIT: The hint above was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1541726).

Comment: When you copy a comment from a previous question, at least acknowledge the author. This is level 1. As level 2, do not close questions to repost them afterwards. As level 3, try to think about the precise hints you receive and to describe where you are stuck.

Comment: I apologize, I edited to give credit. In the future I will take into account your instructions.

Comment: Really? Then reopen the previous version and add your thoughts to it (presently there are none, is there?). An extra feature is that at least 3 previous questions on the site explain this in details.

Comment: Re the edit, note that people are not interested in who gave the hint so much as where is the other question.

Comment: Undeleted. My intention in deleting the post was to ask a more refined question. I will answer my own question there once I solve the problem with martini's hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. The outline is fine, its quite easy to complete it. Here is a guideline:

First recall that $|f|$ being Riemann-integrable means that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for every partition $P$ with fineness smaller then $\delta$, we have
 $$ U(|f|,P) - L(|f|,P) < \epsilon $$
So let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, use the integrability of $f$ to get a $\delta$ for $f$, that is 
$$ U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$$
for partitions fine enough. Then use your inequality and you are done-